# Make relationships immutable

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have the records in a table A that after being created should not be modified. It is straightforward to prevent update of attributes via a trigger.

The problem is that the table A has also a many to many relationship with a table B. Now what I want to do is **prevent the update of the join table** (i.e. the insert/update/delete) for records in table A that has already been created (and not yet deleted).

The purpose is to have not only constant attributes, but also constant relationships. Any idea?

PS I don't know if it is a problem but table A has a composite primary key that could change.

Answer (score 1):

Say your many:many table is TableAB(colA, colB) and it joins tables A and B. Who does the insert on the many:many (join) rows? Do you have control over it? The way I get it, you want this insert to happen just once for a given/fixed row A.

Add a column IsAlreadyMapped in table A. When somebody maps row A to a set S of rows from table B, set this IsAlreadyMapped flag to 1. Note that the set S of rows from B could be also an empty set. Once IsAlreadyMapped set to 1, don't allow anyone else to map the same row A to another set of rows from table B. I think it is simple enough. When you delete the row A (physically or logically) you can update IsAlreadyMapped as needed. Then you can add such column at the table B side too.

I am not sure I know all the details of your requirements,
so I am just throwing out some ideas here. Hope it helps.